# Update elements of dataframe by applying function involving same row elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8   0.1  0.11
11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18  0.2  0.12
21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28  0.3  0.13
31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38  0.4  0.14
```

I want to read EACH ROW and for each value in columns a to h (in that row), subtract value in column i and divide by value in column j and to replace that original value with this resultant value And to update the whole dataframe (from columns a to h).

How should I proceed in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work assuming you're actually working with 8+2 columns:

```
for col in df.columns[:8]:
    df[col]=(df[col]-df['i'])/df['h']
```

Perhaps there's a more efficient way, but this should be easy to understand

Answer (score 4):

You can use reshape columns `i` and `j` and subtract,

```
df = df.iloc[:, :8].sub(df['i'].values[:, None]).div(df['j'].values[:, None]).round(2)

    a       b       c       d       e       f       g       h
0   8.18    17.27   26.36   35.45   44.55   53.64   62.73   71.82
1   90.00   98.33   106.67  115.00  123.33  131.67  140.00  148.33
2   159.23  166.92  174.62  182.31  190.00  197.69  205.38  213.08
3   218.57  225.71  232.86  240.00  247.14  254.29  261.43  268.57
```

Comment: You do not need numpy broadcast here `df.iloc[:, :8].sub(df['i'],0).div(df['j'],0).round(2)
`

Answer (score 3):

Make use of `filter` and the underlying `numpy` arrays.

```
u = df.filter(regex='[^ij]')

res = (u.values - df.i.values[:, None]) / df.j.values[:, None]

pd.DataFrame(res, columns=u.columns)
```

```
            a           b           c           d           e           f           g           h
0    8.181818   17.272727   26.363636   35.454545   44.545455   53.636364   62.727273   71.818182
1   90.000000   98.333333  106.666667  115.000000  123.333333  131.666667  140.000000  148.333333
2  159.230769  166.923077  174.615385  182.307692  190.000000  197.692308  205.384615  213.076923
3  218.571429  225.714286  232.857143  240.000000  247.142857  254.285714  261.428571  268.571429
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `sub` and `div` with index slicing:

```
df.loc[:, 'a':'h'] = df.loc[:, 'a':'h'].sub(df['i'], axis=0).div(df['j'], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
            a           b           c           d           e           f  \
0    8.181818   17.272727   26.363636   35.454545   44.545455   53.636364   
1   90.000000   98.333333  106.666667  115.000000  123.333333  131.666667   
2  159.230769  166.923077  174.615385  182.307692  190.000000  197.692308   
3  218.571429  225.714286  232.857143  240.000000  247.142857  254.285714   

            g           h    i     j  
0   62.727273   71.818182  0.1  0.11  
1  140.000000  148.333333  0.2  0.12  
2  205.384615  213.076923  0.3  0.13  
3  261.428571  268.571429  0.4  0.14
```

Comment: It is changing all values to NaNs. @Scott Boston

Answer (score 2):

A fun method `eval` :-)

```
pd.concat([df.eval('('+x +'-i)'+'/j') for x in df.columns[:8]],axis=1,keys=df.columns[:8]) 
Out[88]: 
            a           b           c  ...           f           g           h
0    8.181818   17.272727   26.363636  ...   53.636364   62.727273   71.818182
1   90.000000   98.333333  106.666667  ...  131.666667  140.000000  148.333333
2  159.230769  166.923077  174.615385  ...  197.692308  205.384615  213.076923
3  218.571429  225.714286  232.857143  ...  254.285714  261.428571  268.571429
[4 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: You could use an f-string here too: `df.eval(f'({x}-i)/j')`

Comment: Sorry but it did not work. TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str  @ WeNYoBen

Answer (score 1):

This manipulates directly on the numpy array

```
df[:] = np.hstack([(df[list('abcdefgh')].values - df[['i']].values)/df[['j']].values, df[['i', 'j']].values])

Out[1566]:
            a           b           c           d           e           f  \
0    8.181818   17.272727   26.363636   35.454545   44.545455   53.636364
1   90.000000   98.333333  106.666667  115.000000  123.333333  131.666667
2  159.230769  166.923077  174.615385  182.307692  190.000000  197.692308
3  218.571429  225.714286  232.857143  240.000000  247.142857  254.285714

            g           h    i     j
0   62.727273   71.818182  0.1  0.11
1  140.000000  148.333333  0.2  0.12
2  205.384615  213.076923  0.3  0.13
3  261.428571  268.571429  0.4  0.14
```